# How do i redraw a pie Chart only once, instead of once for every datalabel it has?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I`m working on charts from HighChart and implemented a button that when pressed, removes the legend from the screen and renders the chart to use the emptied space. But when working with a Pie chart, it seems to redraw the chart for every datalabel the chart has, hereby increasing loading time up to half a minute for a chart that takes 2 seconds to create.

```
 (function(b,a)
 {
 if(!b){
     return
 }
 var c = b.Chart.prototype,d=b.Legend.prototype;b.extend(c,
 {
     legendSetVisibility:function(h)
     {
         var i=this,k=i.legend,e,g,j,m=i.options.legend,f,l;

         if(m.enabled==h)
         {
             return
         }
         m.enabled=h;
         if(!h)
         {
             d.destroy.call(k);
             e=k.allItems;
             if(e)
             {
                 for(g=0,j=e.length;g<j;++g)
                 {
                     e[g].legendItem=a
                 }
             }
             k.group={}
         }
         i.animation= false;
         c.render.call(i);
     },
     legendToggle:function()
     {
         this.legendSetVisibility(this.options.legend.enabled^true)
     }
 })
}(Highcharts));
```

this code is a slight adaptation from http://jsfiddle.net/P2g6H/

Comment: Could you setup demo with that issue? For me it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/P2g6H/30/

Comment: I`m also working with a great deal of cubesviewer and I`m not entirely sure how to fit that into the demo :( but i do appreciate you pointing this out. it made me wonder what other differences there could be, but now it seems as though I`m working on an old version of highcharts, one where it renders the series, i noticed because the object on my site was called 'YA' and on the fiddle it was called 'hb'. I`ve updated to the newest version and this fixes the pie chart problem, now i need to fix all the other charts T_T thanks for your help though, couldn`t have done it without you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently I was still working with an old version of highcharts, updating to the newest version solved the problem.